# App crashes after checking network with this error message : An AVPlayerItem cannot be associated with more than one instance of AVPlayer

Tags: iphone, ios, mpmovieplayercontroller

I'm getting this error mentioned in title while playing a video from internet.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{  
  NSString *urlAdress = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.dailymotion.com/video/x108t8t"];
  //NSString *urlAdress = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"video8" ofType:@"mp4"];in this case video plays.
  NSURL *videoURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:urlAdress];
  self.mpvc = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:videoURL];  

  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(moviePlaybackDidFinish:)
                                             name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                                           object:nil];

  self.mpvc.moviePlayer.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceTypeStreaming;
  //when using file in resources use MPMovieSourceTypeFile,when online then streaming
  [self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:mpvc];
  [super viewDidLoad];
}
//and here is moviePlaybackDidFinish method    
- (void)moviePlayBackDidFinish:(NSNotification *)notification
{
MPMoviePlayerController *theMovie = [notification object];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self
                                                name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                                              object:theMovie];
[theMovie stop];
[theMovie.view removeFromSuperview];
 NSLog(@" playback finish Called......");

}
```

this is whole code. i have went through most of tutorials,stackoverflow questions but could not get a single solution

Comment: Are you using multiple instances of MPMoviePlayerViewController on same screen ?

Comment: Post this method in your question. Its difficult to read this here.

Comment: what  is an avplayeritem i dint used this in my code?

Comment: Have you used AVPlayer anywhere there ? or imported its classes in your code ?

Comment: Your movie player probably isn't being cleaned up so when you play a second video a new movie player is created, causing a conflict with the previous (still alive) one.

Comment: no i dint used AVPlayer neither i imported it

Comment: put [super viewdidload] before adding anything to the method. but I'm not sure it is the problem

Comment: no it doest help.same results

Comment: AVPlayer is the component MPMoviePlayerController uses internally.

Comment: i got solution  please mark it up so people may able to get help. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well this question seems a lot on stack overflow, i got a solution to this. most of the people facing same issue have right code but only problem is we forget to add dailymotion,vimeo frameworks. since they provide their own framework sdks
you can download them from links below and add them to your projects.

http://www.dailymotion.com/doc/api/sdk-objc.html

Answer (score 0):

Your URL is not correctly created for the case you quoted.

You are trying to play a remote stream, hence the URL needs to be a remote one.

Local file URLs are created using `fileURLWithPath`. Remote URLs are created using `URLWithString`.

**Local File URL**

```
NSURL *videoURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"video8" ofType:@"mp4"]];
```

**Remote URL**

```
NSURL *videoURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.dailymotion.com/video/x108t8t"];
```